# Bipartiteness of hypercube graph with at least one edge contracted

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I am participating in a research in my university and as a side task I need to solve the following problem:

> Consider a hypercube graph. Someone contracts one edge in it.
> What is the minimum number of edges more I need to contract to get bipartite graph again?

Is there any extensive theory about hypercube graphs to read so I can find a solution, because, for now, it is not that obvious for me. Or do you have any advises reagarding this problem?

Comment: It might be a good idea to do some small examples, i.e. dimensions $\le 3$, to get a feel for what the pattern might be.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, but for my research it is important to find a solution based on logical conclusions, because this problem originates more complex ones.

Comment: Showing that you've done the minimal research effort towards a solution, rather than merely stating a problem "I need to solve", will help Readers appreciate your interest in the problem (and phrase answers in an expeditious way).  It will also help to clarify the problem (the title suggests  a different problem than the one you seem to be interested in).

Comment: @hardmath But this is my own problem, so I am very intersted in it in some sence, and I just need an advise where to look, because I've never seen books about hypercube graphs and their properties.

Comment: I've made slight edits to your post.  If I've unintentionally changed your meaning, you can rollback to your original or make additional edits to clarify.

Comment: Suppose you start with a (hypercube) graph that is 2-coloured black and white. After contracting some edge, colour the newly formed vertex black or white (in the hypercube it does not matter which because of symmetry). Now simply contract any edges that connect that new vertex to another vertex of the same colour. The net effect is that in the original hypercube, all of the edges of one vertex are contracted, thereby merging that vertex with all its neighbours.

Answer (score 1):

I'll respond in terms of a request for references.

You might be interested in the Wikipedia article on [edge contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction), as this notion seems to be more central to your problem than "hypercube graphs" per se.

A Google search finds this [2011 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.5441.pdf) on "Obtaining a Bipartite Graph by Contracting Few Edges".

In the specific case you describe, an $n$-dimensional hypercube with one edge contracted, it is clear we can attain a bipartite graph by contracting $2^{n-1}-1$ additional edges of the original hypercube, those which were *parallel* to the first contracted edge.

So that gives an upper bound, but I don't know whether it is sharp.  In that respect it is an interesting problem.